# x86 CMP instruction not working for a single word comparison

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, qemu, bootloader

I am having troubles with the `CMP` instruction when comparing single words (2 bytes).
The following is my *main.asm*:

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov bx, HELLO_MSG
call print_string

mov bx, GOODBYE_MSG
call print_string

jmp $

%include "print_string.asm"

; Data
HELLO_MSG:
    db 'Hello, World!', 0
GOODBYE_MSG:
    db 'Goodbye!', 0
```

This is the *print_string.asm* file:

```
print_string:
    pusha
    mov ah, 0x0e
    loop:
        call print_char
        cmp word [bx], 0
        jne loop
    popa
    ret

print_char:
    mov al, [bx]
    int 0x10
    add bx, 1
    ret
```

This code prints out the following:

> Hello World! Goodbye!Goodbye!

I know that when I add

```
db 0
```

in between the *HELLO_MSG* and the *GOODBYE_MSG*, the code will work as intended. Can anyone explain why `CMP` will only work when there are 4 bytes of 0 between the strings?

If anyone is interested in looking at the compiled output, here it is:

```
bb  23  7c  e8  08  00  bb  31  7c  e8  02  00  eb  fe  60  b4
0e  e8  07  00  83  3f  00  75  f8  61  c3  8a  07  cd  10  83           
c3  01  c3  48  65  6c  6c  6f  2c  20  57  6f  72  6c  64  21
00  47  6f  6f  64  62  79  65  21  00  00  00  00  00  00  00           
00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
*           
00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  55  aa
```

The `55 aa` at the end is added by me because I am using this code as a boot loader.

Comment: You are doing `cmp word [bx],0` which compares 2 bytes starting at the address `bx` . You probably want to be comparing a single byte. `cmp byte [bx],0`

Comment: I also suggest you properly set up the segment registers and stack etc. I give some tips in this Stackoverflow answer that has [general bootloader tips](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/3857942)

Comment: You may also want to use a register other than _BX_  for `print_string`. [_Int 10/AH=0Eh_](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm) uses _BH_ as the page number to write to. You probably want to set that to 0. That means you should use a register other than _BX_ as the string pointer. Maybe _SI_ instead.

Comment: Another useful tidbit is to use BOCHS to debug bootloaders. It understands real mode and real mode addressing and can be a valuable tool to debug bootloader code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am using QEMU, which is similar to BOCHS

Comment: QEMU doesn't do real mode debugging very well (it uses GDB which isn't designed for real mode in mind). BOCHS has an internal debugger that is well suited for debugging bootloaders. So yes they do the same thing, but one tool is vastly better off with a debugger that would help you find issues like the one in my first comment.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Your first suggestion works. But why? If you look at the compiled output, the first 2 bytes at line 4 are 0, which should theoretically make CMP evaluate it to be equal to 0.

Comment: Line 4 starts with `00  47  6f` Each one of those values (separated by a space) is a single byte, not 2 bytes. `00` is a single byte of 0, not two bytes of 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the CMP instruction is not working for single word comparison is because a word must contain 2 bytes. Since the compiled output shows that there is only 1 byte between the two messages, you will need to change the size of the CMP instruction from word to byte:

```
cmp byte [bx], 0
```

I made the mistake of assuming that the compiled output format arranged the bytes by 2. However, with the help of the following comment by Michael Petch:

> Line 4 starts with 00 47 6f Each one of those values (separated by a space) is a single byte, not 2 bytes. 00 is a single byte of 0, not two bytes of 0

I was able to realize my mistake.

Comment: ➕1 for learning from your mistakes and answering your own question